# Connecting URL in django

Tags: python, django

I'm spending hours on this thing.

I have a category page, and inside that page there's list of posts that leads to single post page if I click a particular one.

Single post page is working, single category page is working, but a page inside category page is not working, does this make sense?

```
def post(request, slug):#this is my view
    single_post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    single_post.views += 1  # increment the number of views
    single_post.save()      # and save it
    t = loader.get_template('main/post.html')
    context_dict = {
        'single_post': single_post,
    }
    c = Context(context_dict)
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))

def category(request, category_name_slug):
    context_dict = {}
    try:
        category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
        context_dict['category_name'] = category.name

        posts = Post.objects.filter(category=category)
        context_dict['posts'] = posts
        context_dict['category'] = category
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    return render(request, 'main/category.html', context_dict)


this is my url
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+)/$', views.post, name='post'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.category, name='category')

]
```

And  this is my category html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>{{category_name}}</h1>
{% if category %}
    {%if posts %}
    <ul>
        {% for post in posts %}
        <h3><a href="{{ post.slug }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>

        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {%else%}
        <strong>No Pages </strong>
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
{{category_name}} does not exist
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Finally post.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    <head>

    <body>
        <h2>{{single_post.title}}</h2>
        <p>{{single_post.content}}</p>
        <p> Views: {{single_post.views}}
            <br>
            <p>
                {% if single_post.image %}
                <img src="/media/{{single_post.image}}">
            {% endif %}
            </p>
<body>
```

it gives me 404 error, interesting thing is url that's giving me error is 127.0.0.1:8000/category/hello/adele but 127.0.0.1:8000/adele doesn't give me error. so inside category page, i want the access for 127.0.0.1:8000/adele –

Comment: What does "not working" entail? errors? not showing correct page?

Comment: post.html one of your <p> is not closing

Comment: it gives me 404 error, interesting thing is url that's giving me error is http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/hello/adele but http://127.0.0.1:8000/adele/ doesn't give me error. so inside category page, i want the access for http://127.0.0.1:8000/adele/

Comment: Well yes, you don't appear to have a url for `/category/hello/adele`, its unclear to me what your actual problem is, how do you plan on distinguishing between posts and categories?

Comment: problem is solved plz read below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `<a href="{{ post.slug }}">{{ post.title }}</a>` with `<a href="/{{ post.slug }}">{{ post.title }}</a>`

The issue is if the reference in anchor doesnt starts with `/` it means its a relative url and that reference is added to current url. Hope this helps you. Also for further reference please use absolute_url feature of django. Please read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) :)

Comment: holy smoke it worked, I spend 3 hours trying to fix this you sir just saved me, by the way did you see my last comment i left you?i tried to select the answer and it gave me some notification

Comment: I'm sorry but can you explain to me why putting / worked all of sudden?

Comment: I've updated the answer for the issue. Please let me know if that clarifies and accept the answer. :)

Comment: Thank you Soooooooooooooooooooooooooooo Much

Comment: I'm scared to change the code now :) but I read absolute_url feature, little bit confused which parameter I should use to implement. anyway can I ask you one more thing?for registration, i'm using redux app. is it possible to disable email verification for redux app?

Comment: Please read the docs for the same.. I'vent worked on the same.. If its not in the docs, just dive in the code and check.. Or you can ask a new question for the same. and please accept answer so others can get benefit from the same. :)

Comment: There will a Tick symbol just next to answer. Please refer to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work .. btw for your redux its `SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL = False`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#url) template tag:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <h3><a href="{% url 'post' slug=post.slug %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
{% endfor %}
```

This reconstruct the url based on your url configuration, ensuring it is a valid url. Here, `'post'` is the name of the url you defined in your urlconf, and `slug=post.slug` is the parameter you pass to the capturing group in your url regex.